# Как вызвать слот qt асинхронно?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qml

Точнее как выгрузить QObject с сигналами так чтоб интерфейс выполнялся в отдельном потоке, а Ccode в отдельном. Обратная связь подойдет через сигналы или через колбэки или любая другая, но чтоб в сишном коде не привязываться к интерфейсу.

Сейчас выгруженно в таком виде через qmltypes (при выгрузке через setContextProperty тоже самое)

```
class Ccode : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QML_ELEMENT
    QML_NAMED_ELEMENT(Ccode)
    QML_SINGLETON
public slots:
    void start();
signals:
    void started();
}
```

Интерфейс зависает при вызове `Ccode.start()`

Если выносить в тред

```
QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to Ccode(0x7fff658c3e20) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlApplicationEngine(0x7fff658c3e00.
```

Соединение хочется выполнить в QML

```
ApplicationWindow {
    Connections {
        target: Ccode
        function onStarted() {
            console.log("started")
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {

        Ccode.start()

    }
}
```

В функции start работа с железом. Ну для простоты примера:

```
void Ccode::start() {

    QThread::sleep(5);
    emit started();

}
```

Comment: Последним параметром в connect поставить `Qt::QueueConnection`

Comment: Как его выставить в QML?

Comment: Тогда покажите где что с чем соединяется, или вызывается. Короче, место возникновения ошибки

Comment: @AlexanderChernin добавил

Comment: И все это живет в одном потоке?

Comment: Вот Ccode хочу выкинуть в отдельный поток.

Comment: @AlexF можно пример "запустить start в отдельном треде, продолжить не дожидаясь его выполнения, получить стартед в qml" регистрация соединений или колбэков на стороне qml нужна чтоб можно было менять интерфейс не меняя бинарника

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Ccode : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void start();
signals:
    void started();
}
```

Оборачивается внешним классом, где уже сигналы переэмитятся в новый поток:

```
class CcodeProxy : public QObject

    Q_OBJECT

    QML_ELEMENT
    QML_NAMED_ELEMENT(Ccode)
    QML_SINGLETON

signals:
    void _start();
    void started();

public slots:
    void start(){ emit _start(); };
    void _started() { emit started(); };
public:
    Ccode cc;
    QThread mythread;
    explicit CcodeProxy(QObject *parent = nullptr) {
        cc.moveToThread(mythread);
        connect(this, &CcodeProxy::_start, &cc, &Ccode::start, Qt::QueuedConnection);
        connect(&cc, &Ccode::started, this, &CcodeProxy::_started, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного изменил код, вместо сингтона сделал обычный класс и классическую его регистрацию  в qml:

```
class Ccode : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void start() {
        qDebug() << "start";
    }
signals:
    void started();
};
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    qmlRegisterType<Ccode>("com", 1, 0, "Ccode");

    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Теперь main.qml:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    Ccode {
        id: ccode
    }

    Connections {
        target: ccode
        function onStarted() {
            console.log("started")
        }

    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        ccode.start()
    }
}
```

И все работает как часы ( кроме работы сигнала `Ccode::started / qml::onStarted` - это не тестировал )

Comment: в одном треде и у меня работает..

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: @eri У меня не получается воспроизвести вашу ошибку, но вы можете на стороне С++ внутреннюю логику класса Ccode вынести в отдельный поток, который соединить с сигналами самого Ccode (и применить Qt::ConnectionType), которые, в свою очередь, обычным способом обрабатывать в qml. Таким образом вы развяжете gui и логику

Comment: Об этом я уже думал. Прокси класс сделать и двойным коннектом вызывать поток. Я напишу ответ с прокси.. В вашем примере интерфейс фризит на время работы слота

Comment: @eri он однопоточный, поэтому фризит. Делайте с прокси - я так делал когда видеопоток принимал обрабатывал и отображал

Comment: хотелось обойтись без прокси...